# Connecting a Clone Git Repo With An Existing Sandbox Org

Tags: salesforcedx, git

I have a repo (based in bitbucket) that I have cloned.
How can I connect my cloned repo with my sandbox environment?
My IDE is VS Code.

In the past I have created a new project from manifest - however when I do that it creates a separate folder.  As a result I need to manually copy files between my first folder (connected to the SF Sandbox) and the other folder (connected to Git remote).

Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: Is this an existing SFDX project repo?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an SFDX repo (e.g. already in source format, has sfdx-project.json, etc), simply use `SFDX: Authorize an org` from the Command Palette. Follow the prompts to authorize your project folder. Once done, you should be connected.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and Authorize an Org does not appear in the command palette.

Comment: @DavidCheng You need to wait for the extensions to "boot up", which takes a moment. Worst case scenario, you can go to the Terminal and type `sfdx force:auth:web:login -s -a desiredAlias`, and VS Code will pick up the newly authorized org.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I waited and it didn't appear.  I also tried the CLI and it didn't work either -- I still don't get the Salesforce-specific options when I right click on `package.xml`.  I'll create a new question for my issue.

Comment: @DavidCheng Please do. I'll be glad to check it out.